# Need to take variables from user input (Javascript )

Tags: javascript, variables

If the user gives input as something like this: XXX YY ZZ.
What I need to get is , detect XXX as variable and take YY as XXX1(variable1) & ZZ as XXX2(variable2).The values of XXX1 and XXX2 will be used in someother files.

This is the code which I am already using:

```
var str = prompt("Enter the values") ;

var array = str.split(' ');

var X = array[0], X1 = array[1], X2 = array[2];
```

But if an input is given like:

> STACK 12 3 
>  Overflow 13 4

I need to get 12 as STACK1 ,3 as STACK2 and 13 as Overflow1 , 4 as Overflow2. Hope this information is enough.

I am new to javascript, detailed description will be helpful.

Comment: I agree, a detailed description would be helpful, as it is very hard to see what you are trying to do.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow! Please read this guide to help us understand better what you want to do, and to increase the probability of your question being answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: get the input from the input text element and split it using white space, then store it in separate variable

Comment: If I understand your question, you have a single form field where XXX is an arbitrary variable name, and YY and ZZ are two instances of variable XXX? What is the context of this requirement? Some more specifics regarding what the variable represents and how you plan to use the values will lead to better answers.

Answer (score 2):

get the input from the input element and split the input element value using string.split() method. It will separate it in array. So, using array index, you could get those array values in separate variable.

declare those variables globally to get that value from anywhere and any other js file you want. I created a simple demo for you...

**HTML Markup**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="gettxt" />
<input type = "button" onclick="callfun()" value="click me!!"/>
</body>
</html>
```

**Javascript code**

```
var first;
var second;
var third;
function callfun() {
    var gettxt = document.getElementById('gettxt');
    var array = gettxt.value.split(' ');
        first = array[0],
        second = array[1],
        third = array[2];
    alert(first);
    alert(second);
    alert(third);
}
```

**SEE THIS [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/topinavo/1/)**

In this demo I just alert those variable values.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I was able to achieve till that.I want to take array[1] as (value of array[0])1 & array[2] as (value of array[0])2 and , Can you help with this?

Comment: what do you mean by (value of array[0])1 ? could you please explain...
do you want array[0] as a variable name?

Comment: If string is given as Stack 12 3, I want 12 as Stack1 and 3 as Stack2. And also what if there are more than 2 or 3 lines.Check the edited question for detailed description.

Comment: may i know why you need like this?

Comment: Consider three or more lines of input is given, I need to find the first string and use the other two values(as mentioned above) in some other form field because the variables are already stored in that format in the form.

Comment: so you need to use text area.. right?

Comment: Consider a html page with two text fields already ( Asking for values like this System1 :<Value1> <Value2>) and I need to fill those fields by taking input from user . That is possible according to both our codes but what if I have to enter these kind of values for many systems via a single input which appears like as I mentioned in the question.

Comment: what about two dimensional array?

Comment: Can you give a brief description on how to search and set using two dimensional array for my question? What if systems are not predefined?

Comment: like this? http://jsbin.com/topinavo/2/

Comment: But how will this help me in naming values as system1 and system2 in (system:<value><value>) as the names in the form will be predefined as sys1, sys2,sys3 etc.,